# Backup archive of Google Groups messages?

Tags: google, backup, google-groups

I've tried searching for a good solution, but it seems the only way is to actually download the individual .html files for each thread or use some screen-scraping method (which doesn't work so well).

Is there a way to download all the messages from a Google Group?

Answer (score 1):

You could try out [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/)

Full description from their website:

> HTTrack is a [free](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) ([GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.txt),
>   libre/free software) and easy-to-use
>   offline browser utility.
>
> It allows you to download a World Wide
>   Web site from the Internet to a local
>   directory, building recursively all
>   directories, getting HTML, images, and
>   other files from the server to your
>   computer. HTTrack arranges the
>   original site's relative
>   link-structure. Simply open a page of
>   the "mirrored" website in your
>   browser, and you can browse the site
>   from link to link, as if you were
>   viewing it online. HTTrack can also
>   update an existing mirrored site, and
>   resume interrupted downloads. HTTrack
>   is fully configurable, and has an
>   integrated help system.

It is available as WinHTTrack for Windows 2000/XP/Vista/7 and available as WebHTTrack for Linux/Unix/BSD

Comment: have you tried to download https://groups.google.com/forum ?

Comment: Its doesn't work for me